# using Jsoup to extract a table inside several divs

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to use jsoup so as to have access to a table embedded inside multiple div's of an html page.The table is under the outer division with id "content-top". I will give the inner divs leading to the table:  content-top -> center -> middle-right-col -> result .

Under the div result; is table round. This is the table that i want to access and whose rows I need to traverse and print out the data contained in them. Below is the java code I have been trying to use but yielding no results :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.calculator.com/#").data("express", "sin(x)").data("calculate","submit").post();

// give the application time to calculate result before retrieving result from results table

try {                                  
Thread.sleep(10000); 
} 
catch(InterruptedException ex) 
{
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

Elements content = doc.select("div#result") ;
Element tables = content.get(0) ;
Elements table_rows = tables.select("tr") ;
Iterator iterRows = table_rows.iterator();

while (iterRows.hasNext()) {

Element tr = (Element)iterRows.next();
Elements table_data = tr.select("td");
Iterator iterData = table_data.iterator();

int tdCount = 0;
String f_x_value = null;
String result = null;

// process new line
while (iterData.hasNext()) {

Element td = (Element)iterData.next();
switch (tdCount++) {
case 1:
f_x_value = td.text();
f_x_value = td.select("a").text();
break;

case 2:
result = td.text();
result = td.select("a").text();
break;          
}
}
System.out.println(f_x_value + "   " + result ) ;
}
```

The above code crashes and hardly does what I want it to do. PLEASE CAN ANYONE PLEASE HELP ME !!!

Comment: Please explain precisely what behavior you're seeing ("crashes" isn't helpful, a full stack trace is) and what behavior you expect.

Comment: Also, Jsoup.connect().post() is a blocking call -- it will wait for the response from the server.  There's no reason to call Thread.sleep before processing the result.

Comment: As far as I know the website uses javascript to display the result. I'm pretty sure jsoup doesn't execute javascript before parsing. The result div is simply empty when no javascript is executed. I guess you have to investigate the ajax they're using to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String do_conversion (String str)
{
char c;
String output = "{";

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
c = str.charAt(i);

if(c=='e')
output += "{mathrm{e}}";

else if(c=='(')
output += '{';

else if(c==')')
output += '}';

else if(c=='+')
output += "{cplus}";

else if(c=='-')
output += "{cminus}";

else if(c=='*')
output += "{cdot}";

else if(c=='/')
output += "{cdivide}";

else output += c; // else copy the character normally
}

output += ", mathrm{d}x}";
return output;
}
```

@Syam S

Answer (score 0):

The page doesnt directly give you a table in a div with id as "result". It uses an ajax class to a php file and get the process done. So what you need to do here is to first build a json like

```
{"expression":"sin(x)","intVar":"x","upperBound":"","lowerBound":"","simplifyExpressions":false,"latex":"\\displaystyle\\int\\limits^{}_{}{\\sin\\left(x\\right)\\, \\mathrm{d}x}"}
```

The `expression` key hold the expression that you want to evaluate, the `latex` is a [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/) expression and then post it to `int.php`. This expects two arguments namely `q` which is the above json and  `v` which seems to a constant value `1380119311`. I didnt understand what this is.

Now this will return a response like

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <table class="round"> 
   <tbody>
    <tr class="">
     <th>$f(x) =$</th>
     <td>$\sin\left(x\right)$</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="sep odd">
     <th>$\displaystyle\int{f(x)}\, \mathrm{d}x =$</th>
     <td>$-\cos\left(x\right)$</td>
    </tr> 
   </tbody>
  </table> 
  <!-- Finished in 155 ms --> 
  <p id="share"> <img src="layout/32x32xshare.png.pagespeed.ic.i3iroHP5fI.png" width="32" height="32" /> <a id="share-link" href="http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sin%28x%29" onclick="window.prompt(&quot;To copy this link to the clipboard, press Ctrl+C, Enter.&quot;, $(&quot;share-link&quot;).href); return false;">Direct link to this calculation (for sharing)</a> </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

The table in this expression gives you the result and the site uses [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to display it like

[image]

A sample program would be

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class JsoupParser6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Integral
            String url = "http://www.integral-calculator.com/int.php";
            String q = "{\"expression\":\"sin(4x) * e^(-x)\",\"intVar\":\"x\",\"upperBound\":\"\",\"lowerBound\":\"\",\"simplifyExpressions\":false,\"latex\":\"\\\\displaystyle\\\\int\\\\limits^{}_{}{\\\\sin\\\\left(4x\\\\right){\\\\cdot}{\\\\mathrm{e}}^{-x}\\\\, \\\\mathrm{d}x}\"}";
            Document integralDoc = Jsoup.connect(url).data("q", q).data("v", "1380119311").post();
            System.out.println(integralDoc);
            System.out.println("\n*******************************\n");

            //Differential
            url = "http://www.derivative-calculator.net/diff.php";
            q = "{\"expression\":\"sin(x)\",\"diffVar\":\"x\",\"diffOrder\":1,\"simplifyExpressions\":false,\"showSteps\":false,\"latex\":\"\\\\dfrac{\\\\mathrm{d}}{\\\\mathrm{d}x}\\\\left(\\\\sin\\\\left(x\\\\right)\\\\right)\"}";
            Document differentialDoc = Jsoup.connect(url).data("q", q).data("v", "1380119305").post();
            System.out.println(differentialDoc);
            System.out.println("\n*******************************\n");

            //Calculus
            url = "http://calculus-calculator.com/calculation/integrate.php";
            Document calculusDoc = Jsoup.connect(url).data("expression", "sin(x)").data("intvar", "x").post();
            String outStr =     StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(calculusDoc.toString());
            Document formattedOutPut = Jsoup.parse(outStr);
            formattedOutPut.body().html(formattedOutPut.select("div.isteps").toString());
            System.out.println(formattedOutPut);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Update based on comment.**

The unescape works perfectly well. In MathJax you could right click and view the command. So if you go to your site http://calculus-calculator.com/ and try the sin(x) equation there and right click the result and view TexCommand like

[image]

The you could see the commands are exactly the ones which we get after unsescape. The demo site is not rendering it. May be a limitation of the demo site, thats all.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Syam S. Your contribution was very helpful and it works.

Comment: .I am stuck with a similar challenge to the one you provided a solution for. This time around, the source website is http://www.derivative-calculator.net/# and I want to write a program that sends input for example sin(x) via JSOUP and JSOUP will return the result of the problem.. i have been trying to implement similar logic to the one you provided, but I am failing to get it right. please do assist

Comment: Its the same scenario here as well. This time it uses `diff.php` instead of `int.php`. So you should be url http://www.derivative-calculator.net/diff.php and the same arguments q and v like `q:{"expression":"sin(x)","diffVar":"x","diffOrder":1,"simplifyExpressions":false,"showSteps":false,"latex":"\\dfrac{\\mathrm{d}}{\\mathrm{d}x}\\left(\\sin\\left(x\\right)\\right)"} v:1380119305`

You can use chrome developer tools to identify these details :)

Comment: i will post as an answer my sample code for accessing the derivative calculator website. I have tried using the tips of similarity that you posted above, but I am getting an error that is displayed in the returned html as : <td class="error" style="text-align: center;">Sorry, something went wrong.</td>  ..can someone please help me identify where my error is. @Syam S

Comment: That might be due to the change in the value for `v`. I've updated my answer for both integral and differential. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much, your replies really helpful & addressing my challenges. I however have seen a better website with detailed functionality & I wish to switch to that site for my integration calculations. Like before, i am struggling to understand the code lines displayed by Chrome Developer Tools. could you please help me with sample code using Jsoup to perform integration. The website is http://calculus-calculator.com/integral/   .@Syam S

Comment: Its the same as above, but this time the url used is http://calculus-calculator.com/calculation/integrate.php. And the inputs are slightly different but easy. Updated the answer.

Comment: the inputs are for sure easier than the ones before; however the output format is fairly bad. When i try to use the MathJax viewer at http://www.mathjax.org/demos/   to display output returned in the IDE, the human readable output is very ugly. the expected result is hardly visible. this is unlike the case of derivative-calculator and integral-calculator  .is it possible to find a way around this bug and print out a clearer output

Comment: That is because the site uses Unicode escape. The return is actually an html with results stored in script tag. You can un-escape the Unicode  characters and then parse the string to get a more readable output. Use apache-commons-lang for unescaping string. Updated my answer. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: woww .it really works out. i wish i could also find an easier online source for derivatives like this calculus-calculator that wont give me a headache of having to format the input. however, yo edited code works out pretty well, but , at the end of the clean and clear result, it is printing out some redundant stuff like ["OK","1d5f1333425e4b69b29914fa40c4ae6e","\u003Cdiv class=\u0022isteps\u0022\u003E\u003Cp\u003EWe\u ... ] . is there a way of eliminating this redundancy and leaving out a cleaner result.@Syam S

Comment: That is because the response body has some kind of a json which includes a div with class isteps. Actually this is the portion that we are looking for. So you could just rip that part and overwrite the body. `formattedOutPut.body().html(formattedOutPut.select("div.isteps").toString());` Updated my answer. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: for the code commented differential and integral, i have been trying to make an expression parser that can handle any user input and convert it to a latex form that will be similar as in that in String q ;for example; sin(4x) becomes {\\\\sin\\\\left(4x\\\\right)} as shown at the end of string q in the solution you gave. i however suspect that a parser is a longer and laborious way of solving this problem. is there an easier way of handling any user input to a format understood by the servers that does not involve me coding my own expression parser.@Syam S

Comment: made a parser as a method, when properly incorporated with the above code, the code can handle and do calculations for any valid user input. see code below : @Syam S

Comment: hello. can you please assist me with a way of writing the output from the above programs into a text file. I have searched the web for example code but all the examples are for outputting content extracted from static websites(i.e no server involved). @Syam S

Comment: Did you mean to write those system outs to a file?

Comment: yes. i want to write those system outs to a text file @Syam S

Comment: i have managed to solve my previous problem. i actually figured out that i do not need to have the output in a string. i have a final problem that i would want you to help me with .im posting it below.@Syam S

Comment: i am trying to parse the sister website of the code commented calculus. the web address is http://calculus-calculator.com/derivative/ .i have tried to implement similar logic and i did this by changing the line url to url = "http://calculus-calculator.com/calculation/differentiate.php"; .this works quite well but the problem i am encountering is the way the output is being formatted. you can have a preview of the output from link in next comment .[sorry, i don't have enough reputation to upload images] . may you please help me on this final stretch of my project .@Syam S

Comment: The link with the images of a preview ofthe wrongly formatted output and the expected output is at -                  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5bg16421tex6t91/AAC18tdsWsh9_L7aIneARtBea   @Syam S

Comment: I dont have access to dropbox from this network. Will get back to you once i get home :)

Comment: ..i have been working on the final lap, i have found where the problem is .i have uploaded on your answer the problematic code . it is under the comment DIFFERENTIATION. may you please assist me

Comment: the problem happens to be with unescaping the returned document , check line #3. it distorts the latex representation of special characters , such that when printing the final result , for example, instead of printing d/dx it prints out \mthb\diff infront of the answer. so in essence, all special latex characters are being destroyed in the unescaping process .to see what i am saying ; you may run the code and display the result on this online latex viewer : http://www.mathjax.org/demos/  @Syam S

Comment: i have tried different unescaping techniques but they all seem not to work .i dont know if we should apply a different technique ; or u can just add a few lines of code that will solve this problem. please please help me bro.@Syam S

Comment: hi. Thank you very much for your answers to my post. My thesis went well and I got First Grade. I want to extend my knowledge of Jsoup and be able to parse website on my own. Are there any tutorials/websites that you can recommend to me so that I can be able to parse websites whose data dynamically change like the ones above. I have tried to search the internet but I cant find any useful resources, maybe its because I am Googling using incorrect wording @Syam S

Comment: Oh Great. Congrats. And for tutorials I've been using jsoup.org itself. You can refer to http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html for most of the parsings. And use fixefox or chrome developer tools to monitor the network to see the request/responses. Combining both you should be able to parse most of the sites. :)

Comment: thank you. i will try use the hints you suggested. can you please help me parse this website: http://calculus-calculator.com/function-analysis/ in a similar manner as you helped me parse the above sites @Syam S